# Orderby random in specific Woocommerce categories

Tags: php, function, woocommerce

I managed to set products random order in one specific category. Now I would like to add a second category to this code. Can anyone help, I have tried everything.

```php
function custom_catalog_ordering_args_8( $args ) {
  $product_category = 'here I put category name';

  if ( ! is_product_category($product_category) ) return $args;

  // Set default ordering to 'date ID', so "Newness"
  $args['orderby'] = 'rand';

  if( $args['orderby'] == 'date ID' )
    $args['order'] = 'DESC'; // Set order by DESC

  return $args;
}    

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_catalog_ordering_args_8', 20, 1 );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this by passing an array, e.g:

```php
function custom_catalog_ordering_args_8( $args ) {
  $product_categories_random_order = array(
    'here I put category name',
    'here you put another category name'
  );

  if ( ! is_product_category( $product_categories_random_order ) )
    return $args;

  // Set default ordering to 'date ID', so "Newness"
  $args['orderby'] = 'rand';

  if ( $args['orderby'] == 'date ID' )
    $args['order'] = 'DESC'; // Set order by DESC

  return $args;
}    

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_catalog_ordering_args_8', 20, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. Sorry for the time.